# WSO2 CEP Event tables with Teradata DB connection throws Null Exception

Tags: jdbc, nullpointerexception, wso2, teradata, wso2-cep

I’ve try to use event tables in Siddhi engine with connection to Teradata Database through JDBC Teradata driver.

Teradata Database runs as virtual machine on the same machine where WSO2CEP installed.

First of all I’ve put Teradata JDBC driver terajdbc4.jar in the

```
<WSO2CEP_HOME>/repository/components/lib/
```

directory, and additional part of driver tdgssconfig.jar put into

```
<WSO2CEP_HOME>/bin
```

directory. Then I’ve restarted CEP server and  made connection in the “Datasources” with next parameters:

```
Datasource type: RDBMS
Name: Teradata
Datasource provider: default
Driver: com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver
URL: jdbc:teradata://192.168.96.128/LOG=DEBUG
User name: xxxxx
Password: xxxxx
```

Test connection works fine.

I’ve created a new Execution Plan which join incoming data flow with Teradata db.

```
@Export('pcrf_out:1.0.0')
define stream pcrf_out (meta_event string, meta_user_id int, value int);

@Import('pcrf_in_filtered:1.0.0')
define stream pcrf_in_filtered (meta_event string, meta_user_id int, value int);

@From(eventtable='rdbms', datasource.name='Teradata', table.name='user_profile')
define table user_profile (user_id int, usual_traf_usg int);

/* JOIN WITH RELATIONAL TABLE */

from pcrf_in_filtered as a join user_profile as b
    on a.meta_user_id == b.user_id and b.usual_traf_usg==100
select a.meta_event as meta_event, a.meta_user_id as meta_user_id, a.value as value
<i>insert into pcrf_out;
```

When I run script validation then I see an error message: Null

Audit.log contains next message:

```
ERROR {AUDIT_LOG}-  Illegal access attempt at [2016-05-04 08:19:38,0813] from IP address null while trying to authenticate access to service EventProcessorAdminService
```

Wso2carbon.log

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-05-05 13:26:37,361] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.admin.EventProcessorAdminService} -  Exception when validating execution plan 
org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.exception.ExecutionPlanConfigurationException: Error while initialising the connection, null
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.internal.util.helper.EventProcessorHelper.validateExecutionPlan(EventProcessorHelper.java:193)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.internal.CarbonEventProcessorService.validateExecutionPlan(CarbonEventProcessorService.java:493)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.admin.EventProcessorAdminService.validateExecutionPlan(EventProcessorAdminService.java:329)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:169)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
    at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:430)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.stub.EventProcessorAdminServiceStub.validateExecutionPlan(EventProcessorAdminServiceStub.java:2207)
    at org.apache.jsp.eventprocessor.validate_005fsiddhi_005fqueries_005fajaxprocessor_jsp._jspService(validate_005fsiddhi_005fqueries_005fajaxprocessor_jsp.java:73)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CSRFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CSRFPreventionFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CRLFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CRLFPreventionFilter.java:59)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.wso2.siddhi.core.exception.ExecutionPlanRuntimeException: Error while initialising the connection, null
    at org.wso2.siddhi.extension.eventtable.rdbms.DBHandler.<init>(DBHandler.java:79)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.extension.eventtable.RDBMSEventTable.init(RDBMSEventTable.java:119)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.helper.DefinitionParserHelper.addEventTable(DefinitionParserHelper.java:99)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.ExecutionPlanRuntimeBuilder.defineTable(ExecutionPlanRuntimeBuilder.java:74)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.ExecutionPlanParser.defineTableDefinitions(ExecutionPlanParser.java:194)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.util.parser.ExecutionPlanParser.parse(ExecutionPlanParser.java:140)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.validateExecutionPlan(SiddhiManager.java:69)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.core.SiddhiManager.validateExecutionPlan(SiddhiManager.java:75)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.processor.core.internal.util.helper.EventProcessorHelper.validateExecutionPlan(EventProcessorHelper.java:191)
    ... 74 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:254)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
    at org.wso2.siddhi.extension.eventtable.rdbms.DBHandler.<init>(DBHandler.java:73)
    ... 82 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:246)
    ... 88 more
```

The same Execution Plan works fine with Mysql connection.

Can anybody help me with it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Based on above stacktrace similar exception can only occur when there is no any such datasource in the server as specified in the query ([See](https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/blob/v3.0.5/modules/siddhi-extensions/event-table/src/main/java/org/wso2/siddhi/extension/eventtable/rdbms/DBHandler.java#L79))

Are you sure that you defined a datasource as specified in the query below (Same name, case also identical)..

@From(eventtable='rdbms', datasource.name='**Teradata**', table.name='user_profile')

Answer for next query--------

To make it work, we have to define db mappings for new database types (By default, it has mappings for h2, mysql, mssql and oracle).. Then please add below entry in db mapping file. You can find a file called rdbms-table-config.xml inside the siddhi-extension-event-table_3.0.5.jar (which is in /repository/components/plugins folder). Please add below property in that file and update the jar file.. Here, you need to add the db meta name as mapping name.. See [here](https://github.com/wso2/siddhi/blob/release-3.0.5/modules/siddhi-extensions/event-table/src/main/java/org/wso2/siddhi/extension/eventtable/rdbms/DBHandler.java#L422)..

```
<mapping db='teradata'>
     <elements/>
</mapping>
```

Comment: Hi Mohanadarshan! You are right! my connection called 'teradata'. When i fixed it i got a new error (I've been turned on trace). Please see full error stack here: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fzczbicwkh6wka1/wso2cep_jdbc_err?dl=0)